# Why Use a Private Docker Registry?

Tags: docker

Why would someone use a private docker registry when they could just share their dockerfile's in source control and have docker image consumers build directly from the dockerfile with `docker build`?

To my untrained eye the private docker registry seems to serve the same purpose as source control except it adds complexity because it's been decoupled from the branch of code that you're in and so you (or your CI/CD server more to the point) has to reconstruct which tag to pull.

Comment: The same reason that people use Artifactory instead of building all artifacts themselves locally - because it takes time that can be used to do something else instead of repeating the same building instructions a hundred/thousand times by every single user

Comment: @Smutje My CI/CD server is doing a `docker build` anyway when it pushes to a registry, so I don't find the saves time argument very compelling.  Are there any other benefits?

Comment: Yeah, when you're a single user - but when 10 other guys use your image without the need to build it, you save 10*the amount of time it takes to build it. As I said, simply compare a registry to Artifactory or similar, it's the same mechanism.

Comment: depending on what is done in the dockerfile it takes time to build ... we have a larger app that takes about 20 minutes to build.. and after that the docker container is tested.

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy on real machines (say you have a job that deploys on 10 machines), usually you don't really want to rebuild the image over and over again.

Instead you can build image once, store it somewhere (???) then maybe deploy on test environment, run some tests, make sure its a good image indeed (starts, tests pass, etc) and then deploy on production.

So this "somewhere" means that you should have some registry, and if you don't want to use docker hub - you can use private docker registry.

This makes sense from both security (don't publish on cloud if you don't need to)
and performance (moving images between servers in private network is faster).

If you're running kubernetes you can also configure it to pull the images from the docker registry and run pods based on these images as specified in the kubernetes deployment files.

If you're running on AWS you can use docker registry to run services like Fargate or ECS. They will take care of scaling out across machines (pretty much like k8s does) but they still need to take the images from somewhere, well, its a private registry (in this case in the cloud called ECS - Elasctic Container Registry).

Bottom line, in many (simple) cases you can live without it, but in some other cases it comes pretty handy

Comment: "usually you don't really want to rebuild the image over and over again".  This seems circular. Can you please explain why?  Is it just for speed?  From a security standpoint not using a registry seems like it would be a smaller attack surface.  The kubernetes example is compelling, thank you.

Comment: It depends on what exactly is in the image but usually it boils to: time, resource availability (maybe you need a compiler to run to prepare an image, maybe building the image requires prescence of libraries, git repository, etc. You dont want all these on real servers that run the dockerized process

Comment: @Lee That’s one of the main advantages of using Docker: you don’t need your entire build environment in production. Example: you prepare one image to install a bunch of libraries and npm and whatnot, test and compile your TypeScript files there, and then [copy those to a minimal web server image](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds) which will go to production. You’d only want that resulting image containing the web server and your Javascript in your repository from which you can spin up a dozen web servers immediately.